# How does one "keep something in mind"?

Tags: kavana-concentration

On my way in to shul, I was stopped by the rabbi. He told me that so-and-so was unavoidably detained and would not be able to say kaddish for his father-in-law. He gave me the deceased's [name](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/99042/is-there-a-need-to-to-know-the-deceaseds-name-when-studying-in-his-merit) and asked me to "have him in mind." I said "yes" reflexively and went in to shul.

There are many situations where we talk about having someone or something in mind. Someone else makes a [bracha](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/88447/birkat-hamazon-with-everyone-in-mind) and "has me in mind" and I have in mind to be yotzei. I make a [bracha](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17968/having-dessert-in-mind) on one thing but have something [else](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/52811/what-is-considered-having-in-mind-for-other-food-items-for-the-same-bracha-categ) "in mind" as well. We can [learn](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/45148/how-does-my-having-someone-in-mind-when-i-learn-help-them) "for" someone and have that person in mind.

But how exactly do we do that? When I was saying kaddish, was I supposed to think of the name I was given while saying the words? For every kaddish? For the duration of the kaddish or just at certain points? I don't usually think of my father's name while I am saying kaddish so am I doing something wrong?

The same holds for other cases of "having in mind" - do I have to be thinking actively and "linguistically" [I am aware that he is saying the bracha and I intend for him to help me fulfill my obligation] or do I just listen with awareness and that's enough? Do I have to time my declaration or maintain it in mind the entire time?

This might overlap with the notion of having [kavannah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/27800/kavannah-of-shem-havayeh-in-the-first-line-of-kriat-shma) in any mitzvah situation, but for there to be any [kavannah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/30493/prayer-with-negative-kavvanah), does one need to formulate a specific statement? Is there a threshold of awareness?

Comment: I believe "have in mind" just means to have intent. There is no specific formula to follow, as long as one intends that the blessing etc. cover whichever food.

Comment: I don't know whether to write this as an answer (because it only answers the last line and not the main question), but r' Chaim brisker talks about needing to have kavana that 'I am doing a mitzva' for the entire duration of the mitzva

Comment: https://he.m.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%97%D7%99%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%99_%D7%A8%27_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D/%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%AA%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%94

Comment: It might also answer how kavana to be "yotzei yedei chova" via someone else works, actually. But I don't think it has anything to do with the other type of kavana- having "someone in mind" (Vs the more common type, which is "having the mitzva in mind")